# An address bar similar to the one in facebook iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c

I need a component that is similar to the address bar that facebook is using:
- a address field with refresh/cancel icon 
- a progress bar that shows how much has been loaded
Is there any ready component?

Comment: Would you mind sharing an image for the non-FBers as me?

Comment: Hi Jenox, actually what I want is similar to the safari's address bar: Lhttp://www.instablogsimages.com/1/2012/03/22/image_title_jdjp2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is to check out the library the facebook app uses- Three20 library (link [here](http://three20.info/)).